# Can we deploy a Java EE war file to Google App Engine without any changes?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hi I have a jee application(war file) running on tomcat 7 and  mysql 5.5. 
Can i run the same war file on google-App-Engine without any modifications? 
If so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot. At minimum App Engine requires configuration file named appengine-web.xml.

> In addition to the web.xml deployment descriptor, an App Engine Java
>   application uses a configuration file, named appengine-web.xml, to
>   specify the app's registered application ID and the version identifier
>   of the latest code, and to identify which files in the app's WAR are
>   static files (like images) and which are resource files used by the
>   application.

Beside that it depends on your application requirements. App Engine offers two environments - [sandboxed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java) and [Maneged VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/java). In case of sandboxed environment there are other [restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Java_The_sandbox) you have to take into account:

- Read-only access to the filesystem
- 60s request limit (in case of automatic scaling type)
- 32 MB request/response size limit
- Subset of the JRE classes (The JRE Class White List)
- Threads can’t “outlive” the request that creates them
- Max 50 concurrent threads per request